# How do I run a LINQ operator asynchronously?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, asynchronous, async-await

Without using Rx, how do I invoke a standard LINQ operator asynchronously?

If the operators on `IQueryable<T>` don't support asynchrony, then that would steal from us the real benefits of making their callers `async` as most of the cost would be inside of these operators.